# Check if varchar() is an int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've inherited a table in a third part app that contains both strings and ints - I want to split the table but want to know the fastest way to determine if the value is an int?  Column is varchar(250)

```
e.g.
Save
123456
Edit
Save
123455
Delete
123444
```

Comment: @TabAlleman I'd suggest that's a poor duplicate. Most of those answers recommend the use of `ISNUMERIC`, which is an awful function in truth (take `SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('1.1') = 1 THEN CONVERT(int, '1.1') END;`  for example). `TRY_CONVERT` is a far better option than those mentioned there.

Comment: I know that a lot of the answers on that question are for 2008 functionality, but there is one answer that mentions using TRY_CONVERT() with 2012+.  Seems to me that the SO thing to do is to add upvotes to that answer in the duplicate question, rather than add this duplicate to the site, which doesn't contribute anything new in the question itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using `TRY_CONVERT`, which will return `NULL` if the value cannot be converted:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(int, YourColumn) AS intColumn
FROM YourTable
--WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, YourColumn) IS NOT NULL --If you only want rows that converted.
```

If you prefer the syntax, you also have `TRY_CAST` (`TRY_CAST(YourColumn AS int)`).

Comment: haha seems we posted the same thing yet again.

Comment: @SeanLange SO's push notifications are whacked out.  I don't always see another answer posted until minutes after the fact.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know what you mean. There we no answers posted when I clicked submit but then instantly there were two others. :)

Comment: Interestingly I saw Tim's very quickly, but i didn't even see Sean's after I got the comment notification. I had to F5.

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to use SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT col
FROM yourTable
WHERE col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```

Using `TRY_CONVERT` might also be an option, but only if you are using a more recent version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
declare @Something table(SomeVal varchar(50))

insert @Something values
('Save')
, ('123456')
, ('Edit')
, ('Save')
, ('123455')
, ('Delete')
, ('123444')

select *
from @Something s
where TRY_CONVERT(int, s.SomeVal) is not null
```